# React tsx - How to pass an array to node

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-typescript, react-tsx

I am using axios to get an array from a JSON file and I want to use the same array over multiple nodes / pages.

Currently I'm using this on each page `var printers = GetPrinters();`

I was trying call `GetPrinters()` from the App.tsx and pass it to each page via a router but I couldn't seem to get that to work. Is there a way I can store the array on state and access it on any node?

I plan to make 4 more pages similar to MonoPrints.tsx that all need access to the data from the array, they won't be updating the array at all, just accessing it.

I would like to use the best practice for this kind of thing and am stuck with repeating the call for each page at the moment.

Site Structure:
**App.tsx**

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { TonerLevels } from "./pages/TonerLevels";
import { MonoPrints } from "./pages/MonoPrints";
import { MonoCopies } from "./pages/MonoCopies";
import { ColourPrints } from "./pages/ColourPrints";
import { ColourCopies } from "./pages/ColourCopies";

export function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/TonerLevels" element={<TonerLevels />}></Route>
        <Route path="/MonoPrints" element={<MonoPrints />}></Route>
        <Route path="/MonoCopies" element={<MonoCopies />}></Route>
        <Route path="/ColourPrints" element={<ColourPrints />}></Route>
        <Route path="/ColourCopies" element={<ColourCopies />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Pages/
**TonerLevels**

```
export function TonerLevels() {
  var printers = GetPrinters();
  return (
    <div>
      <Nav></Nav>
      <table className="table table-dark table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>IP</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Serial</th>
            <th>Black %</th>
            <th>Yellow %</th>
            <th>Magenta %</th>
            <th>Cyan %</th>
            <th>K1 %</th>
            <th>K2 %</th>
            <th>Current Monthly Prints</th>
            <th>Current Monthly Copies</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody className="table-group divider">
          {printers
            ? printers.map((printer) => {
                return (
                  <tr key={printer.address}>
                    <td>{printer.location}</td>
                    <td>
                      <a
                        href={"//" + printer.address}
                        target="_blank"
                        rel="noopener noreferrer"
                      >
                        {printer.address}
                      </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>{printer.name}</td>
                    <td>{printer.serial}</td>
                    <td>{printer.black > -1 ? printer.black : ""}</td>
                    <td>{printer.yellow > -1 ? printer.yellow : ""}</td>
                    <td>{printer.magenta > -1 ? printer.magenta : ""}</td>
                    <td>{printer.cyan > -1 ? printer.cyan : ""}</td>
                    <td>{printer.k1 > -1 ? printer.k1 : ""}</td>
                    <td>{printer.k2 > -1 ? printer.k2 : ""}</td>
                    <td>{getPrints(printer)}</td>
                    <td>{getCopies(printer)}</td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })
            : null}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Services/
**PrinterServices**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const PRINTER_REST_API_URL = "http://localhost:8080/GetReport";

export interface Printer {
  address: string;
  black: number;
  monoCopies: number;
  monoPrints: number;
  colourCopies: number;
  colourPrints: number;
  cyan: number;
  k1: number;
  k2: number;
  location: string;
  magenta: number;
  name: string;
  serial: string;
  yellow: number;
  Reports: [
    {
      month: string;
      monoPrints: number;
      monoCopies: number;
      colourPrints: number;
      colourCopies: number;
    }
  ];
}

export function GetPrinters() {
  const [printers, setPrinters] = useState<Printer[] | null>();
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(PRINTER_REST_API_URL).then((response) => {
      setPrinters(response.data);
    });
  }, []);
  return printers;
}
```

EDIT:
Typescript of the code that worked from serod:

```
const Context = createContext<Printer[] | undefined>(undefined);

interface ContextProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export const ContextProvider: React.FC<ContextProviderProps> = ({
  children,
}) => {
  const [printers, setPrinters] = useState<Printer[]>();
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(PRINTER_REST_API_URL).then((response) => {
      setPrinters(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return <Context.Provider value={printers}>{children}</Context.Provider>;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "React Context" to store the array on a global state and then access it from any component.

Context code would look like this in Javascript:

```js
import React, { useState, createContext, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Context = createContext();

export const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [printers, setPrinters] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("PRINTER_REST_API_URL").then((response) => {
      setPrinters(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        printers,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

export default Context;
```

Then add ContextProvider in your app.js

```js
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { TonerLevels } from "./pages/TonerLevels";
import { MonoPrints } from "./pages/MonoPrints";
import { MonoCopies } from "./pages/MonoCopies";
import { ColourPrints } from "./pages/ColourPrints";
import { ColourCopies } from "./pages/ColourCopies";

export function App() {
  return (
    <ContextProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/TonerLevels" element={<TonerLevels />}></Route>
          <Route path="/MonoPrints" element={<MonoPrints />}></Route>
          <Route path="/MonoCopies" element={<MonoCopies />}></Route>
          <Route path="/ColourPrints" element={<ColourPrints />}></Route>
          <Route path="/ColourCopies" element={<ColourCopies />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ContextProvider>
  );
}
```

Now you can simply use `useContext` hook to access the printers state from any component.

Comment: I had to edit the code a little for typescript, but it worked thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are options available to maintain state at higher level and consume it across the components.

1. `Context API` - helps passing data deeply into the tree and can be accessible only within the hierarchy. (Official doc: https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext).
2. `React Redux` - Manages state at app level and can be accessible from any components. (Official doc: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/getting-started)

Option 1 can be used for your case as it looks simpler and manageable.

Option 2 can be used for large scale application with complex state management.

Comment: I had trouble understanding the docs, but with serod's example it makes sense.